# Video Editor: Set render output size to match source

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have imported a movie file into the video editor with an unconventional aspect. How can I set the output render size to match the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open tab like shown in picture and type your resolution

[image]

Comment: That didn't fix it, unfortunately. Is there a way to tell the source to fit to rendered output? Because the source and the render output appear to have the same aspect but different resolutions.

Comment: @jettam By typing resolution in that two boxes you telling it "to fit to rendered output" Can you open Movie Clip Editor hit "N" and it right upper corner you have "Footafge Settings" and can you show whats resolution and fps you have there, like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHC52.png

Answer (score 1):

Add a move or image strip to the VSE, select it so it gets a white outline and become the active strip. Movie strip options becomes avalible in the Strip menu. Select "Set Render Size":

[image]